# I can't generate a PWM signal DSPIC33CK32MC102

Tags: microchip, dspic

I'm a beginner with dspic and I'm trying to generate a pwm signal to control a buck. However, observing the output signal, the pin always remains in the same state (LOW). Has anyone ever suffered from this?

PWM.c

```
void PWM_Initialize (void)
{
    // MODSEL Independent Edge; TRGCNT 1; CLKSEL Master clock; ON enabled; 
    PG1CONL = 0x8;
    // MCLKSEL FOSC - System Clock; LOCK disabled; DIVSEL 1:2; 
    PCLKCON = 0x00;
    // FSCL 0; 
    FSCL = 0x00;
    // FSMINPER 0; 
    FSMINPER = 0x00;
    // MPHASE 0; 
    MPHASE = 0x00;
    // MDC 0; 
    MDC = 0x00;
    // MPER 16; 
    MPER = 0x10;
    // LFSR 0; 
    LFSR = 0x00;
    // CTA1EN disabled; CTA2EN disabled; CTA3EN disabled; CTA4EN disabled; 
    CMBTRIGL = 0x00;
    // CTB3EN disabled; CTB2EN disabled; CTB1EN disabled; CTB4EN disabled; 
    CMBTRIGH = 0x00;
    // PWMLFA PWMS1 or PWMS2;; S1APOL Positive logic; S2APOL Positive logic; PWMLFAD No Assignment; PWMS1A PWM1H; PWMS2A PWM1H; 
    LOGCONA = 0x00;
    // PWMLFB PWMS1 | PWMS2; S2BPOL Positive logic; PWMLFBD No Assignment; S1BPOL Positive logic; PWMS2B PWM1H; PWMS1B PWM1H; 
    LOGCONB = 0x00;
    // PWMLFC PWMS1 | PWMS2; PWMLFCD No Assignment; S2CPOL Positive logic; S1CPOL Positive logic; PWMS1C PWM1H; PWMS2C PWM1H; 
    LOGCONC = 0x00;
    // PWMS1D PWM1H; S1DPOL Positive logic; PWMLFD PWMS1 | PWMS2; PWMLFDD No Assignment; S2DPOL Positive logic; PWMS2D PWM1H; 
    LOGCOND = 0x00;
    // PWMS1E PWM1H; PWMS2E PWM1H; S1EPOL Positive logic; PWMLFE PWMS1 | PWMS2; S2EPOL Positive logic; PWMLFED No Assignment; 
    LOGCONE = 0x00;
    // S1FPOL Positive logic; PWMS2F PWM1H; PWMS1F PWM1H; S2FPOL Positive logic; PWMLFFD No Assignment; PWMLFF PWMS1 | PWMS2; 
    LOGCONF = 0x00;
    // EVTASEL PGTRGSEL bits; EVTASYNC Not synchronized; EVTAPOL Active-high; EVTAPGS PG1; EVTASTRD Stretched to 8 PWM clock cycles minimum; EVTAOEN disabled; 
    PWMEVTA = 0x00;
    // EVTBPGS PG1; EVTBSYNC Not synchronized; EVTBPOL Active-high; EVTBSEL PGTRGSEL bits; EVTBSTRD Stretched to 8 PWM clock cycles minimum; EVTBOEN disabled; 
    PWMEVTB = 0x00;
    // EVTCPGS PG1; EVTCPOL Active-high; EVTCSEL PGTRGSEL bits; EVTCSTRD Stretched to 8 PWM clock cycles minimum; EVTCSYNC Not synchronized; EVTCOEN disabled; 
    PWMEVTC = 0x00;
    // EVTDOEN disabled; EVTDSTRD Stretched to 8 PWM clock cycles minimum; EVTDPOL Active-high; EVTDPGS PG1; EVTDSEL PGTRGSEL bits; EVTDSYNC Not synchronized; 
    PWMEVTD = 0x00;
    // EVTEOEN disabled; EVTEPOL Active-high; EVTEPGS PG1; EVTESTRD Stretched to 8 PWM clock cycles minimum; EVTESEL PGTRGSEL bits; EVTESYNC Not synchronized; 
    PWMEVTE = 0x00;
    // EVTFPOL Active-high; EVTFPGS PG1; EVTFSTRD Stretched to 8 PWM clock cycles minimum; EVTFSEL PGTRGSEL bits; EVTFOEN disabled; EVTFSYNC Not synchronized; 
    PWMEVTF = 0x00;
    // MSTEN disabled; TRGMOD Single trigger mode; SOCS Self-trigger; UPDMOD SOC update; MPHSEL disabled; MPERSEL disabled; MDCSEL disabled; 
    PG1CONH = 0x00;
    // TRSET disabled; UPDREQ disabled; CLEVT disabled; TRCLR disabled; CAP disabled; SEVT disabled; FFEVT disabled; UPDATE disabled; FLTEVT disabled; 
    PG1STAT = 0x00;
    // FLTDAT 0; DBDAT 0; SWAP disabled; OVRENH disabled; OVRENL disabled; OSYNC User output overrides are synchronized to the local PWM time base; CLMOD disabled; FFDAT 0; CLDAT 0; OVRDAT 0; 
    PG1IOCONL = 0x00;
    // PENL enabled; DTCMPSEL PCI Sync Logic; PMOD Complementary; POLL Active-high; PENH enabled; CAPSRC Software; POLH Active-high; 
    PG1IOCONH = 0x0C;
    // UPDTRG Manual; ADTR1PS 1:1; PGTRGSEL EOC event; ADTR1EN3 disabled; ADTR1EN1 disabled; ADTR1EN2 disabled; 
    PG1EVTL = 0x00;
    // ADTR2EN1 disabled; IEVTSEL EOC; SIEN disabled; FFIEN disabled; ADTR1OFS None; CLIEN disabled; FLTIEN disabled; ADTR2EN2 disabled; ADTR2EN3 disabled; 
    PG1EVTH = 0x00;
    // PSS Tied to 0; PPS Not inverted; SWTERM disabled; PSYNC disabled; TERM Manual Terminate; AQPS Not inverted; AQSS None; TSYNCDIS PWM EOC; 
    PG1FPCIL = 0x00;
    // TQPS Not inverted; LATMOD disabled; SWPCI Drives '0'; BPEN disabled; TQSS None; SWPCIM PCI acceptance logic; BPSEL PWM Generator 1; ACP Level-sensitive; 
    PG1FPCIH = 0x00;
    // PSS Tied to 0; PPS Not inverted; SWTERM disabled; PSYNC disabled; TERM Manual Terminate; AQPS Not inverted; AQSS None; TSYNCDIS PWM EOC; 
    PG1CLPCIL = 0x00;
    // PCIGT disabled; TQPS Not inverted; SWPCI Drives '0'; BPEN disabled; TQSS None; SWPCIM PCI acceptance logic; BPSEL PWM Generator 1; ACP Level-sensitive; 
    PG1CLPCIH = 0x00;
    // PSS Tied to 0; PPS Not inverted; SWTERM disabled; PSYNC disabled; TERM Manual Terminate; AQPS Not inverted; AQSS None; TSYNCDIS PWM EOC; 
    PG1FFPCIL = 0x00;
    // PCIGT disabled; TQPS Not inverted; SWPCI Drives '0'; BPEN disabled; TQSS None; SWPCIM PCI acceptance logic; BPSEL PWM Generator 1; ACP Level-sensitive; 
    PG1FFPCIH = 0x00;
    // PSS Tied to 0; PPS Not inverted; SWTERM disabled; PSYNC disabled; TERM Manual Terminate; AQPS Not inverted; AQSS None; TSYNCDIS PWM EOC; 
    PG1SPCIL = 0x00;
    // PCIGT disabled; TQPS Not inverted; SWPCI Drives '0'; BPEN disabled; TQSS None; SWPCIM PCI acceptance logic; BPSEL PWM Generator 1; ACP Level-sensitive; 
    PG1SPCIH = 0x00;
    // LEB 0; 
    PG1LEBL = 0x00;
    // PWMPCI PWM1; PLR disabled; PLF disabled; PHR disabled; PHF disabled; 
    PG1LEBH = 0x00;
    // PHASE 0; 
    PG1PHASE = 0x00;
    // DC 18; 
    PG1DC = 0x12;
    // DCA 0; 
    PG1DCA = 0x00;
    // PER 177; 
    PG1PER = 0xB1;
    // TRIGA 0; 
    PG1TRIGA = 0x00;
    // TRIGB 0; 
    PG1TRIGB = 0x00;
    // TRIGC 0; 
    PG1TRIGC = 0x00;
    // DTL 0; 
    PG1DTL = 0x00;
    // DTH 0; 
    PG1DTH = 0x00;
    
    PG1CONLbits.ON = 1;
}
```

SYSTEM.C

```
// Configuration bits: selected in the GUI

// FSEC
#pragma config BWRP = OFF    //Boot Segment Write-Protect bit->Boot Segment may be written
#pragma config BSS = DISABLED    //Boot Segment Code-Protect Level bits->No Protection (other than BWRP)
#pragma config BSEN = OFF    //Boot Segment Control bit->No Boot Segment
#pragma config GWRP = OFF    //General Segment Write-Protect bit->General Segment may be written
#pragma config GSS = DISABLED    //General Segment Code-Protect Level bits->No Protection (other than GWRP)
#pragma config CWRP = OFF    //Configuration Segment Write-Protect bit->Configuration Segment may be written
#pragma config CSS = DISABLED    //Configuration Segment Code-Protect Level bits->No Protection (other than CWRP)
#pragma config AIVTDIS = OFF    //Alternate Interrupt Vector Table bit->Disabled AIVT

// FBSLIM
#pragma config BSLIM = 8191    //Boot Segment Flash Page Address Limit bits->8191

// FOSCSEL
#pragma config FNOSC = FRCDIVN    //Oscillator Source Selection->Internal Fast RC (FRC) Oscillator with postscaler
#pragma config IESO = OFF    //Two-speed Oscillator Start-up Enable bit->Start up with user-selected oscillator source

// FOSC
#pragma config POSCMD = NONE    //Primary Oscillator Mode Select bits->Primary Oscillator disabled
#pragma config OSCIOFNC = OFF    //OSC2 Pin Function bit->OSC2 is clock output
#pragma config FCKSM = CSECMD    //Clock Switching Mode bits->Clock switching is enabled,Fail-safe Clock Monitor is disabled
#pragma config PLLKEN = ON    //PLL Lock Enable->PLL clock output will be disabled if LOCK is lost
#pragma config XTCFG = G3    //XT Config->24-32 MHz crystals
#pragma config XTBST = ENABLE    //XT Boost->Boost the kick-start

// FWDT
#pragma config RWDTPS = PS2147483648    //Run Mode Watchdog Timer Post Scaler select bits->1:2147483648
#pragma config RCLKSEL = LPRC    //Watchdog Timer Clock Select bits->Always use LPRC
#pragma config WINDIS = OFF    //Watchdog Timer Window Enable bit->Watchdog Timer in Window mode
#pragma config WDTWIN = WIN25    //Watchdog Timer Window Select bits->WDT Window is 25% of WDT period
#pragma config SWDTPS = PS2147483648    //Sleep Mode Watchdog Timer Post Scaler select bits->1:2147483648
#pragma config FWDTEN = ON_SW    //Watchdog Timer Enable bit->WDT controlled via SW, use WDTCON.ON bit

// FPOR
#pragma config BISTDIS = DISABLED    //Memory BIST Feature Disable->mBIST on reset feature disabled

// FICD
#pragma config ICS = PGD1    //ICD Communication Channel Select bits->Communicate on PGC1 and PGD1
#pragma config JTAGEN = OFF    //JTAG Enable bit->JTAG is disabled

// FDMTIVTL
#pragma config DMTIVTL = 0    //Dead Man Timer Interval low word->0

// FDMTIVTH
#pragma config DMTIVTH = 0    //Dead Man Timer Interval high word->0

// FDMTCNTL
#pragma config DMTCNTL = 0    //Lower 16 bits of 32 bit DMT instruction count time-out value (0-0xFFFF)->0

// FDMTCNTH
#pragma config DMTCNTH = 0    //Upper 16 bits of 32 bit DMT instruction count time-out value (0-0xFFFF)->0

// FDMT
#pragma config DMTDIS = OFF    //Dead Man Timer Disable bit->Dead Man Timer is Disabled and can be enabled by software

// FDEVOPT
#pragma config ALTI2C1 = OFF    //Alternate I2C1 Pin bit->I2C1 mapped to SDA1/SCL1 pins
#pragma config SMB3EN = SMBUS3    //SM Bus Enable->SMBus 3.0 input levels
#pragma config SPI2PIN = PPS    //SPI2 Pin Select bit->SPI2 uses I/O remap (PPS) pins

// FALTREG
#pragma config CTXT1 = OFF    //Specifies Interrupt Priority Level (IPL) Associated to Alternate Working Register 1 bits->Not Assigned
#pragma config CTXT2 = OFF    //Specifies Interrupt Priority Level (IPL) Associated to Alternate Working Register 2 bits->Not Assigned
#pragma config CTXT3 = OFF    //Specifies Interrupt Priority Level (IPL) Associated to Alternate Working Register 3 bits->Not Assigned
#pragma config CTXT4 = OFF    //Specifies Interrupt Priority Level (IPL) Associated to Alternate Working Register 4 bits->Not Assigned

#include "pin_manager.h"
#include "clock.h"
#include "system.h"
#include "system_types.h"
#include "pwm.h"
#include "interrupt_manager.h"
#include "traps.h"

void SYSTEM_Initialize(void)
{
    PIN_MANAGER_Initialize();
    INTERRUPT_Initialize();
    CLOCK_Initialize();
    PWM_Initialize();
    INTERRUPT_GlobalDisable();
    SYSTEM_CORCONModeOperatingSet(CORCON_MODE_PORVALUES);
}

/**
 End of File
*/
```

main.c

```
#ifndef FCY
#define FCY CLOCK_InstructionFrequencyGet()
#endif

#include "mcc_generated_files/system.h"
#include "mcc_generated_files/pwm.h"
#include "mcc_generated_files/clock.h"
#include <libpic30.h>
#include <p33CK32MC102.h>
/*
                         Main application
 */
int main(void)
{
    // initialize the device
    SYSTEM_Initialize();
    PWM_Initialize();
    PWM_GeneratorEnable(1);
    PWM_Enable();
    PWM_PeriodSet(1,0xFFFF); 
    PWM_GeneratorEventStatusClear(1,PWM_GENERATOR_INTERRUPT_CURRENT_LIMIT);
    PWM_GeneratorEventStatusClear(1,PWM_GENERATOR_INTERRUPT_FAULT);
    PWM_GeneratorEventStatusClear(1,PWM_GENERATOR_INTERRUPT_FEED_FORWARD);
    PWM_GeneratorEventStatusClear(1,PWM_GENERATOR_INTERRUPT_SYNC);
   while (1)
    {
        __delay_ms(5); 
     PWM_DutyCycleSet(1, 75);
      __delay_ms(5);
      PWM_DutyCycleSet(1, 15);
    }
 
}
/**
 End of File
*/
```

I searched for information in the official documentation and on forums, but I was unsuccessful in any attempt. There seems to be a locked register